# How can I display a single out of range message with the Range validator in Symfony2/3?

Tags: php, validation, symfony, annotations, doctrine

The [Range](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/constraints/Range.html) constraint in Symfony2 allows you to specify minimum and maximum values with messages to be shown depending on the input being over or under the limits.

```
 /**
  * @Assert\Range(
  *      min = 120,
  *      max = 180,
  *      minMessage = "You must be at least {{ limit }}cm tall to enter",
  *      maxMessage = "You cannot be taller than {{ limit }}cm to enter"
  * )
  */
```

How can I specify a generic message that's not about the minimum or the maximum? For eg.:

```
 /*
  * ...
  *      outOfRangeMessage = "You must be between {{ min }} and {{ max }} to enter."
  * ...
  */
```

There is no such `outOfRangeMessage` parameter. There is an `invalidMessage` parameter, but that's only returned when the input isn't a number at all, which doesn't work for my purpose.

The worst way to do it is to hard-code the `min` and `max` values and repeat the message twice, like this:

```
 /*
  * ...
  *      minMessage = "You must be between 120 and 180 to enter.",
  *      maxMessage = "You must be between 120 and 180 to enter."
  * ...
  */
```

but this is terrible.

Comment: You have no other choice thant create your own validator.

Comment: @Alsatian That's not a bad idea at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. You can only use `limit` and `value` params inside the messages. Also you can override `RangeValidator:validate` method to add more params

Comment: This sounds interesting. Can you elaborate on the overriding part? Can you point to an example?